# How to stick QDockWidget right or left to another without central widget [UNRESOLVABLE]

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I want to stick QDockWidget to another QDockWidget to left or right, but don't know how to do this in PyQt.

In project QMainWindow has no any central widget and if i do mw.addDockWidget it always raises in bottom of all dock widgets of this window, but i want to raise it in left of the concrete dock widget.

Can i do this with Qt?

Comment: The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) states -- "Note: Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder."  Try adding a minimally sized central widget.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I read inattentively the user manual...